# Is there a way to represent a conditional loop in an entity relations diagram?

Tags: sql, database, entity-relationship

So, I am designing a ERD for a renting outlet where the user can either borrow an item or make reservations, if the item is unavailable. I created two relationships namely; **Borrow** and **Reserve** between the **USER** entity and the **ITEM** entity. But, i figured there should be an additional loop indicating that, reservation should only be made if the item to be borrowed is currently UNAVAILABLE. Is there a way to represent this in a ERD? I am using the Chen notation.

Comment: So what? UML or ERD? There is no ERD in UML.

Comment: ERD pls. Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.